# PHP script dies when run via CRON job

Tags: php, phpseclib

Let me start by saying I am totally not a PHP programmer - this was dumped on me to fix.

I have a function that sits in a file by itself, that basically looks like this:

```
<?php
function UploadFile($source, $destination){
   $debugLogPath = '/biglongpath/debug.log';
   file_put_contents($debugLogPath,PHP_EOL . "Beginning UploadFile function", FILE_APPEND);

    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
    require_once('Net/SFTP.php');

    ...Rest of the ftp code here...
}

?>
```

It's using phpseclib. If I run the main PHP script (that calls this function...) via a web browser, everything works great. When I run that same script via a CRON job, it dies as soon as this function is called. I've verified this by writing out a debug log right before calling the function - the first statement before the function is written to the log, but the "Beginning UploadFile function" is never written.

I'm guessing that maybe it has something to do with the require_once statement - maybe either a path problem or permissions issue when it's executed via CRON?

I've tried wrapping the entire function contents in a try/catch and writing out the Exception, but it still just dies.

Comment: The user running the cron job probably doesn't have permission to write to the debug.log file.

Comment: There's a different `php.ini` file for scripts run from the shell (CLI) or from the webserver. Maybe the CLI version doesn't have the directory containing `Net/SFTP.php` in the include search path.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you running and which PHP version?

Comment: My guess: try putting in the absolute path to the phpseclib directory instead of the relative path in the `set_include_path`. Maybe as an alternative to that you could, in the cronjob, do `cd /path/to/ && php path.php` instead of just `php path.php` (which is probably what you're currently doing)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why there are 3 helpful flags, when the question states, that the file is being written? However, this is not the CLI error log and therefore will not automagically log any errors there.
The second one suggestion made appears more likely, while there are even more possibilities:

Make sure that these modules are being loaded for the PHP-CLI:

`libsodium`, `openssl`, `mcrypt`, `gmp` (as the `composer.json` hints for).

Running `php --ini` should show which INI files were loaded. Even if the corresponding INI files are there, make sure the instructions inside them are not commented out with a `;`.

Manually running the script from CLI, as the user which runs the cronjob suggested, with error reporting enabled. If this shouldn't help, single-step into it with `xdebug`, to see where exactly it bugs out (NetBeans, Eclipse, VS Code and a few other IDE do support PHP debugging). This requires some effort to set it up, but then it provides a far better debugging methodology.